# How much can one (on average) increase chest voice range before reaching genetic potential?

Tags: voice, vocal-range, tenor

I have been receiving singing lessons for 3 months now, from (I believe to be) a fantastic vocal coach. I have managed to increase my range in this time, from my highest note being G4, to achieving B5 (on a good day), just below the ever-desirable tenor high C.

How much more range can I expect to gain before reaching my genetic potential? I don't feel like each semi-tone I learn are becoming harder or taking longer to master yet.

Answer (score 1):

B5 is a pretty good upper range for a choir soprano or a mezzosoprano, almost an octave above tenor high C (which is C5).

Yet you are asking about chest voice range.  That alone will likely limit the usefulness of an answer to you.

The problem with "genetic potential" is that this does not tell you anything about *sustainable* and *musically useful* range and what that B4 (which I assume you have meant to be writing) actually means in that context is not likely to be known to readers of this group than it will be to your vocal teacher.  If anybody, you should be asking her or him.  And if that does not result in an answer you are satisfied with, it is extremely unlikely that you'll get a more useful answer from people who never heard you sing, nor participated in your vocal development so far.

At any rate, after 3 months of lessons it is certainly too early to apply for a singing scholarship or sign contracts for musical or opera singing, so there is little point in fixing a target tessitura right now.

Comment: Pretty important point, musical usefulness. In some excercises I am sometimes able to hit the tenor high c (I'm a baritone). But when singing songs (I sing mostly Rock and Metal) and can't reach that note or sing the same octave without sacrificing control, expression and sustain. Of course, I am working on it to fix that, but it's propably unlikely that this will work like I hope it would =) But he's right, no one knows your full potential. Work with what you have and aim for the stars, if you get stuck somewhere in between you already came a long way =)

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to predict how your voice will respond to training.

I recommend that you focus on other aspects at this stage, such as tonal quality, dynamics, expressiveness, dramatic presentation, breath control, diction, and how you form your vowels.  Etc.  Also go to recitals and find out what approaches to singing you like best.  And sing in a good choir.